# NHibernate - How to log Named Parameterised Query with parameter values?

Tags: nhibernate, named-query, parameterized-query

I have a parameterised named Query like this :

```
Query moveOutQuery = session.createSQLQuery(moveOutQueryStr.toString())
                .addEntity(MyClass.class)
                .setParameter("assignmentStatus", Constants.CHECKED_OUT)
```

I want to see the actual SQL query with parameters filled in. However while debugging I only get the following query:

> `Select * from my_assignment WHERE assignment_status in ( :assignmentStatus )`

Why isn't the `assignmentStatus` being substituted for its real value?

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't the assignmentStatus being substituted for its real value?

This is because NHibernate use query parameters to input values. This is efficient in *many* cases and also helpful against SQL Injection attack. Parameters are sent separately. You can find them at the bottom if SQL is logged as explained below.

---

You may log each SQL to file as explained below.

This is implemented through [`log4net.dll`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/); you need to add reference.

Add namespaces as below:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Core;
using log4net.Layout;
using log4net.Repository.Hierarchy;
```

Configure `log4net` in NHibernate as below:

```
Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders();

FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
fileAppender.Name = "NHFileAppender";
fileAppender.File = logFilePath;
fileAppender.AppendToFile = true;
fileAppender.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
fileAppender.Layout = new PatternLayout("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}:%m%n%n");
fileAppender.ActivateOptions();

Logger logger = hierarchy.GetLogger("NHibernate.SQL") as Logger;
logger.Additivity = false;
logger.Level = Level.Debug;
logger.AddAppender(fileAppender);

hierarchy.Configured = true;
```

You also need to set `ShowSql` while configuration as below:

```
configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ShowSql, "true");
configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.FormatSql, "true");
```

You need to call this code once at startup of your application. Output log includes values of parameters as well.

Following is the code:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM MyEntity WHERE MyProperty = :MyProperty")
            .AddEntity(typeof(MyEntity))
            .SetParameter("MyProperty", "filterValue")
            .UniqueResult<MyEntity>();
```

Following is the logged query:

> ```
> 2020-01-09 14:25:39:
>     SELECT
>         * 
>     FROM
>         MyEntity 
>     WHERE
>         MyProperty = @p0;
>     @p0 = 'filterValue' [Type: String (4000:0:0)]
> ```

As you can see, parameter value `filterValue` is listed at the bottom.

This works for all query APIs like `IQueryOver`, `IQuery`, `ISQLQuery` etc.

This logs both success and failed statements. You can play with [`FileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_FileAppender.htm) and [`Logger`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Repository_Hierarchy_Logger.htm) class to meet your additional requirements.

Also refer [`PatternLayout`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Layout_PatternLayout__ctor_1.htm) from [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Layout_PatternLayout.htm). More details can also be found [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html), [here](https://www.codejava.net/coding/common-conversion-patterns-for-log4js-patternlayout) and [here](http://spoiledtechie.com/post/2015/11/19/Conversion-Patterns-for-Log4Net.aspx). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1102026/5779732) Q/A discusses the same.

Following Q/A may also help:

- [Get executed SQL from nHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1264132/5779732)
- [Using log4net to write to different loggers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17106559/5779732)
- [How to log SQL calls with NHibernate to the console of Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/474659/5779732)

As you see, this logs the parameter values at bottom of the query. If you want those logged embedded in the query, please refer to [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249154/Logging-NHibernate-Queries-with-Parameters) article.