# How to I move hibernate.cfg into appsettings.json

Tags: .net-core, nhibernate

For NHibernate and .NET Core, I have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=.;Database=OrmCookbook;Trusted_Connection=True;</property>

    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

1. What is the syntax for putting it in my `appsettings.json` file?
2. What is the syntax for loading said json file?

---

Alternately, if it possible to move just the connection string into `appsettings.json`? That's the one I need to control the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in comment, configuration by code is also acceptable solution to you. Following is how you can configure NHibernate Session Factory by code:

Import the namespaces:

```
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Cfg.MappingSchema;
```

Following is the configuration code:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, "YourDialect");
configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, "YourConnectionString");
configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.DefaultSchema, "YourDefaultSchema");
configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Isolation, "ReadCommitted");
configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.BatchSize, "YourBatchSize");
configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ShowSql, "true");
configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.FormatSql, "true");
configuration.AddMapping(YourHbmMappingInstance);
configuration.SessionFactory().DefaultFlushMode("YourFlushMode");

ISessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

For `AddMapping` method, you need to provide an `Assembly` in which you have defined your mappings.

Call this code once at the startup of application. Maintain instance of `sessionFactory` throughout the application life time to create `ISession`.

Further, if you want to configure log4net for logging, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54182578/5779732) answer.

Comment: I ended up just using the hibernate.cfg.xml file and just overwrote the connection string with `configuration.SetProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to give a `IDictionnary<string, string>` to the Nhibernate configuration. It is the common denominator between `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration` and Nhibernate configuration.

For instance, if your Nhibernate settings are in a `NHibernate` section in the appsettings.json :

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings":{
    "myconnstring":"..."
  },
  "NHibernate": {
    "connection.connection_string_name":"myconnstring",
    "dialect": "NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQL83Dialect",
    "current_session_context_class": "async_local",
    "cache.use_second_level_cache": true,
    "transaction.use_connection_on_system_prepare": false,
    "cache.provider_class": "NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider, NHibernate",
    "cache.use_query_cache": false
  }
}
```

Then you can build your `ISessionFactory` like that :

```cs
IDictionary<string, string> nHibernateSettings = config.GetSection("NHibernate")
    .GetChildren()
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);

if(nHibernateSettings.TryGetValue(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionStringName, out string? connStringName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connStringName))
{
    nHibernateSettings[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString] = config.GetConnectionString(connStringName);
}

var conf = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration() { Properties = nHibernateSettings };
conf.AddAssembly("your assembly name");
ISessionFactory sf = sessionFactory = conf.BuildSessionFactory();
```